# sharepoint 2007 custom error message

Tags: database, sharepoint

For a sharepoint application, we have 5 content databases each dedicated to hold one site collection. Eventually, we dettached one content database from SQL server and so from sharepoint central administration.
Now, when user tries to access that perticular site url or any list/libraries within that site, they recieve a common 404 site not found error!.
is there any possibility to show them a customized error message like "The content has been removed by administrator" which should be displayed when user tries to access any content within this site collection which is being removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just override the Error page, and show them your customized message if they have entered a URL that matches the removed site.

Refer to this article for creating a custom error page:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ketaanhs/archive/2010/03/13/moss-sharepoint-2007-custom-error-page-and-access-denied-page.aspx